# Verify that method argument exists on disk

Tags: c#, integration-testing, moq

I have an object that I want to test. It's supposed to call a method called `ProcessFile()`, which takes a filename as input. This method is mocked.

I can easily verify that the method is called the expected number of times. The actual filenames are randomly generated, *however* if you call `ProcessFile()` then clearly the file that it's supposed to be processing *must* exist on disk. If it doesn't, something is broken.

Currently the code under test is broken; it's sometimes calling the method with non-existent filenames. I really, really, really want the error message to say *which file* didn't exist.

I was able to sort-of kind-of get the test to detect that something is wrong like so:

```
mockProcessor.Verify(
  x => x.ProcessFile(It.Is<string>(s => s != null && File.Exists(s)),
  Times.Exactly(103)
);
```

Now the test fails if any of the files don't exist on disk. However, it fails claiming that the method wasn't called the required number of times. I understand *why* it says this, but that's a *highly* misleading message. The *real* problem is the files not existing on disk - a fact which the test output doesn't make especially clear. *I* know what's going on, but the next poor #### to work on this code may not have a clue.

What I really want is to check that the required number of invocations has occurred, and that in each such invocation, the specified file existed on disk. Any suggestions?

Comment: You really should not be using files on disk, you should be using fake files in code.

Comment: @SamLeach Not possible. This isn't a unit test, it's an integration test.

Comment: I see. I've added the integration-testing tag.

Comment: If it's an integration test, why are you using a Moq to test whether the file exists not the production code for `ProcessFile()`?

Comment: @StuperUser We have tests for `ProcessFile()` elsewhere. _This_ test is for whether that method is being called correctly - which it isn't, in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution using callbacks:

```
Action<string> callback = (file) => Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(file));

mockProcessor.Setup(x => x.ProcessFile(It.IsAny<string>)).Callback(callback);
```

As it turns out, the bug I'm trying to hunt down depends on the fact that `ProcessFile()` *deletes* the file after processing. Naturally it's trivial to add that to the above callback.

So now I can go about actually trying to fix the bug...

Answer (score 1):

You could change `s => s != null && File.Exists(s)` into a statement body:

```
s => 
{
    if (s == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!File.Exist(s))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(s);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or extract a method and call that (`s => FileNotNullAndExists(s)`).